# Created Custom Product Attribute but Not showing in Configuration Section in magento 2

Tags: magento2

attributes are not shown under this area ,

Step 2: Attribute Values
Select values from each attribute to include in this product. Each unique combination of values creates a unique product SKU.

Comment: I have fetch same issue so set visible as a true .

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into the same roadblock myself. The solution is to make sure that the scope of the attributes you want to use is set to "Global".

[image: Scope setting on attribute]